# DOM element addclass not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, dom

i am creating div using `DOM Element` as

```
phototab = document.createElement('div');
phototab.setAttribute('class', 'phototab fleft');
//phototab.className = "phototab fleft";
```

i tried both methods but it is not adding class in IE7

Comment: Where do you insert it into the DOM and then confirm it's not working?

Comment: are you finally appending the DIV to document??

Comment: You're right about `setAttribute()` however `className` works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/n32Cq/3/

Comment: alex  Pranav : i am calling a javascript function with values and appending this div to a parent div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `setAttribute()` to affect things that are actually **properties** of DOM elements.

```
phtototab.className = 'phototab fleft';
```

should work. (It's an IE thing; other browsers are less picky, but for IE a property is a property and an attribute is an attribute.)

*edit* — I should say that you *shouldn't* use `.setAttribute()` when it's unnecessary.

Comment: How does one know what is an attribute and what is a property?

Comment: Well you just have to check the browser docs. All of the attributes you can set in standard HTML, to my knowledge, are manifested as object properties of DOM nodes.  That includes "id", "tagName", "type", "className", "name", "style", "checked", "selected", "for", "href", "src", and so on.

Comment: both setAttribute() and className works for others browsers except IE7.

Comment: That's what I thought and how I code.  So, when do you have to use `setAttribute()`?

Comment: I think `.setAttribute()` (in old IE, where it matters) is for non-standard HTML attributes mostly.

Answer (score -1):

How about jQuery?

```
phototab = $("<div>").addClass("phototab fleft");
```

That's all! Very simple. :)

Comment: True enough but it's considered bad form around here to push jQuery on a question that doesn't mention it in the tags.

Comment: But he doesn't say he doesn't want jQuery. This is just a suggestion for him.

Comment: @zuber Surya, You see, `$("<div>")` is your DOM Element.